# Draw several Numbers around a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As per below fiddle, I tried to draw number circle , but I want this circle to start always from 0 at top , how can I achieve that behaviour.

Also I want to connect numbers from inner circle border to number with dotted line, how can I draw dotted line

http://jsfiddle.net/ineffablep/x03f61db/

```
function createFields() {
    $('.field').remove();
    var container = $('#container');
    for(var i = 0; i < +$('input:text').val()+1; i++) {
        $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'field',
            'text': i 
        }).appendTo(container);
    }
}

function distributeFields() {


    var fields = $('.field'), container = $('#container'),
        width = center.width()*2, height = center.height()*2,
        angle = 0, step = (2*Math.PI) / fields.length;
    var radius = width/2;
    var containerLength=$('input:text').val();
    angle=step* (containerLength-1);

    fields.each(function() {

        var x = Math.round(width + radius * Math.cos(angle));
        var y = Math.round(height + radius * Math.sin(angle));
            $(this).css({
            right: x + 'px',
            top: y + 'px'
        });
        angle -= step;

    });
}
 var center = $('#center');

$(window).resize(function(height) {

    $('#container').width($(window).height()*0.9)
    $('#container').height($(window).height()*0.9)
    var width = $('#container').width() * 0.4;
     console.log("width",$('#container').width());
    console.log("height",$('#container').height());
    var radius = width/2;
    width += 'px';
    radius += 'px';
    center.css({
        width: width, height: width,
        '-moz-border-radius' : radius,
        '-webkit-border-radius' : radius,
        'border-radius' : radius
    });

createFields();
distributeFields();
    // rest of your code for font-size setting etc..
});

$(window).resize();


$('input').change(function() {
    createFields();
    distributeFields();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial angle must be changed.

```
angle = -90*Math.PI/180; // (deg) * [Math.PI/180 == rad to deg]
//We have to provide values in radians, so we convert our degrees to radians
```

[check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/x03f61db/2/)

Comment: Hi thanks, this is what I need , How can I draw dotted  lines to connect each number from inner circle border

Comment: Actually I recommend using a canvas element for your task... You could even accomplish connecting inner circle with numbers.. I will post a jsFiddle soon if you are OK with using canvas.

Comment: Hi Vinod, I am happy to use Canvas or SVG  , As I am not good in svg , canvas used jquery